# How can I run QCL (quantum programming language) on Windows?

Tags: quantum-computing, qcl

I'm sure someone must have done this before. I've tried compiling QCL for Cygwin but it just doesn't work. If someone has already managed to compile it for Cygwin can you please post a copy? Or alternatively suggest an easier way to run it in Windows.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source please?

Comment: Source: http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/qcl.html

Answer (score 5):

Today I compiled for windows the latest (0.6.3) version of qcl. Remove `set LANG=ru_RU.CP866` line from `qcl-win.bat` if you don't need to configure locale.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70139310/qcl-0.6.3.zip